# Remove last occurrence of pattern and everything after that

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to remove last occurrence of a pattern "\[uU]" and everything after it from a string.

Example:

> input: ab00cd\u00FF\U00FF0000

> output: ab00cd\u00FF

I am doing this currently with something like `lastIndexOf` and `substring` and I wonder if there is a Regex way to do it. I figure it might involve lookarounds?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Please add the tag to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match `\U` that isn't followed by `\U`.

You haven't said what language you're using, so the generic solution is:

```
Search: \[uU](?!.*\[uU]).*
Replace: <blank>
```

The negative look-ahead `(?!.*\[uU])` asserts that `\U` (or `\u`) do not appear anywhere after the leading match.